# How to make Ubuntu sshd configuration writable during secure ftp?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

My current **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file says this:

```
# override default of no subsystems
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    interal-sftp

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server

Match Group sftp_users
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ChrootDirectory /home
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I have added myself (user-id) to the sftp_users group, restarted SSHd service etc., and I do get the login/password prompt when attempting to open secure-FTP connection to this host, but then from the remote SFTP client (PSFTP on Windows 10 machine) I find that the destination directory is "/" (root) and it is obviously not writable. Trying to do a change-directory to /home/myuser fails, so this appears to be a CHROOT root. What can I do s.t. after logging-in I can get to /home/myuser and find it writable ?

Comment: login  to SFTP as user-id instead of root.

Comment: Actually, I am logging in as user-id, not as root.